# Multiple matches on same row

Tags: mysql, sql

Say for example I have one Order coupled with multiple items.
How do I list them on the same row (for example 3 items) ?

I already tried this

```
SELECT order.ID, item.name , item.qty , item2.name,item2.qty,item3.name,item3.qty
FROM order
JOIN item ON order.id = item.id
JOIN item as item2 ON order.id = item2.id
JOIN item as item3 ON order.id = item3.id
```

But how to avoid selecting the same item multiple times ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is expected output ??

Comment: Do you mean `groupconcat` ?

Comment: What rdbms are you using? What is wrong with the sql you have posted?

Comment: Just mySQL but does it select default distinct rows for multiple joins ?

Comment: If one order has several rows in any of the other tables, you will get several rows for that order. But why do you have tables item, item2 and item3, isn't just item enough?

Comment: Updated it's only one table :)

Comment: But why join the same table several times? (I can't see no reason in this case, since you just join with order table.)

Comment: Don't. That's not how you're supposed to handle relational data. What's wrong with having multiple rows for multiple items? Or, since you likely don't need this in a list (if you do, you might want to revise your overal desing), a separate query for the order data followed by another query for all its items? If you really need to list all the items of multiple orders, you will probably want to use `xml`.

Comment: @jalh He wants the first item to be in `item`, the second one in `item2` etc.  Obviously, it doesn't work :)

Comment: @Luaan I am using a very old system that has a SQL parser (slow). One order (in this case) can have a maximum of like 3 items. But I want to select those items as well in the same query.

Comment: The use LEFT JOIN if there are 1 to 3 items. You also have to add ON conditions to pick 1:st, 2:nd and 3:rd item only... (How do you chose item1, item2 and item3?)

Comment: Just the JOIN is enough to get the rows but I can have different rows (1-3) but I don't want any duplicates. Maybe with LIMIT & OFFSET ?

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL you can write a query as:

```
DECLARE @order TABLE (id int)
INSERT INTO @order VALUES (1)

DECLARE @item TABLE (id INT,NAME VARCHAR(10),qty INT)
INSERT INTO @item VALUES (1,'A',1),(1,'B',1),(1,'C',3)


SELECT
    O.id AS OrderId,
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ', Name:' + NAME + ', Qty:' + CAST (qty AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM @item I
            WHERE I.Id = O.Id
            ORDER BY I.Id
            FOR XML PATH(''), type
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS Models
FROM
    @order O
```